# In H2 db something like query log available like in mySQL?

Tags: bash, h2

I want to rotate the log like in mySQL, but now for an H2 db. Is there such a log available and how do I rotate it in a bash script ?

Example for mySQL:

```
#Rotate the MySQL query log
echo '' > /usr/local/mysql/var/mysql_queries.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the H2 database, if you append [`;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=2`](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#trace_options) to the database URL, then the SQL statements that are executed are written to the file `{databaseName}.trace.db`. There is also a [tool to analyze this trace](http://h2database.com/html/performance.html#database_profiling) file.